# Is there a better way to implement PUT method in Express than explicitly assigning values?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, put

Is there a better way to implement the PUT method in Express than explicitly assigning each value from the request to a db loaded object (from MongoDB)?

```
  function put(req, res) {
    const { school } = req;
    school.name = req.body.name;
    school.nature = req.body.nature;
    school.website = req.body.website;
    school.facebookURL = req.body.facebookURL;
    school.instagramURL = req.body.instagramURL;
    ...
    req.school.save((err) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.send(err);
      }
      return res.json(school);
    });
  }
```

My document has quite a lot of attributes and the JSON will get quite complex. I am relatively new to Express and would like to know if there is a trick to do this more optimally.

Comment: `mongoObject = {...mongoObject, ...req.body}`? please explain

Comment: hi @LawrenceCherone, I've just added a code snippet to my original question. I am loading and forwarding a 'school' (Mongo object) in a middleware function.

Comment: many fields dose increase lines which is why one may abstract it abit, you could use a loop or look into making a strict merger where the original object defines whats updated, bit like Object.assign but strict i.e [like](https://gist.github.com/lcherone/460bf9392b1c8bba57276ecf7e8cada9) though mongo or underscore might have something more robust, don't forget validation..

Comment: thanks @LawrenceCherone for your valuable input, I will look into that now. Btw. I am doing some of the validation directly on the schema (using "required" attributes), but will add more as I go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the hint given to me by @LawrenceCherone in the comments, I came up with a pretty elegant solution to the problem. I am doing the validation in the model schema, so the code here can be short and sweet!

```
function put(req, res) {
    const { school } = req;

    Object.assign(school, req.body);

    req.school.save((err) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.send(err);
      }
      return res.json(school);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the loaded object(school) is a mongodb collection.

You can use the **update** method of the collection without explicitly specifying the data to update.

```
function put(req, res) {
    const { school } = req;
    school.update({
      _id:ObjectId(req.param.id)
    },
    req.body)
      .then(function (success) {
          res.json();
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            res.status(404).send(err);
        }); }
```

ps: on mobile device right now, so formatting might be poor.

Comment: Hi Collins, thanks a lot for offering your perspective, but I couldn't make it work. I found a solution, though, I will be posting it below.